Pausing react native expo Audio when playing a videoUrl
I am trying to create a audio player in my chatapp with the following code.  While I managed to create the audio player, it can only play the whole audio file without the stop or pause functions.  The below code is the extract of my code for the audio player:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  HStack,
  Icon,
  Slider,
  Spinner,
  Text,
  Button,
  NativeBaseProvider,
} from "native-base";
import { MaterialIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { Audio } from "expo-av";

export const AudioPlayerView = (props) => {
  const {
     duration,
     audioUrl,
  } = props;

  const [sound, setSound] = useState();
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState({});
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const [currentDuration, setCurrentDuration] = useState(0);
  const [totalDuration, setTotalDuration] = useState(0);

 
  async function playAudio() {
    const { sound, status } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
      { uri: audioUrl },
      { isLooping: false }
    );
    setSound(sound);
    setStatus(status);

    if (status.isLoaded) {
      console.log("Play Audio");
      await sound.playAsync();
      setIsPlaying(true);
      setActive(true);
    }

    sound.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate((playbackStatus) => {
      if (playbackStatus.isPlaying) {
        setCurrentDuration(playbackStatus.positionMillis);
        setTotalDuration(playbackStatus.durationMillis);
      }
      if (playbackStatus.didJustFinish) {
        setIsPlaying(false);
        setActive(false);
        setCurrentDuration(0);
        sound.unloadAsync();
      }
    });
  }

  //
  async function pauseAudio() {
    console.log("Pause Audio");
    await sound.pauseAsync();
    setIsPlaying(false);
    setActive(false);
  }
  //

  useEffect(() => {
    return sound
      ? () => {
          setIsPlaying(false);
          sound.unloadAsync();
          setSound(null);
        }
      : undefined;
  }, [sound]);

.
.
.
}

Grateful if anyone could advise how I can add the pause function and resume function after pause.  Thanks in advance!
